# Adding another className to react button component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add an extra `className` for my `<Button />` component but it's not adding the new `className`.

I have the Button component that contains

```js
import React from 'react'; 
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Button = ({ children, type, onClick }) => {
    return (
        <Link to="/" className="btn-mobile">
            <button className={`btn`} onClick={onclick} type={type}>
                {children}
            </button>
        </Link> 
    )
}
```

I'm calling `<Button />` from another file and trying to add an extra `className` to that button but that's not working.

```html
<div className="ticket">
   <Button className="ticket"> Visit Now</Button>
</div>
```

When I checked the Developer Tools Elements, the **Visit Now button** only has the className of `btn`.

How can I add an extra `className` in this instance?

Comment: Please provide the full code of Button.js so that we can understand and reproduce how you are passing the arguments to it.

Comment: This is my full code of Button.js
`import React from 'react'; <br>
import './Button.css';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const Button = ({children, type, onClick,}) =>{

    return (

        <Link to="/" className="btn-mobile">

            <button className= {`btn`} onClick = {onclick} type = {type}>
                {children}
            </button>
        </Link>
    )
}`

Comment: @RichardNguyen You should add full code in the question itself with indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Button.js should be like this.

```
const Button = ({ className, onClick, type, children }) => (
   <button className= {className} onClick={onClick} type={type}>{children}</button>
);
```

You can make it simple as follows.

```
const Button = props => <button {...props} />;
```

Then export the `Button` as default.

```
export default Button;
```

Comment: I can see that second example working for valid button attributes, but what does the `<button>` element do with `children`?

Comment: Here is the example. It will work with `children` as well.
https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-banach-2w6ge?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Create a variable using both the default button class, and the classname passed down in props in a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), and then use that variable as the `className`.

Here's a full working example.

```js
function Button(props) {

  const {
    classname,
    handleClick,
    type,
    children
  } = props;
  
  const classnames = `btn ${classname}`;
  
  return (
    <button
      className={classnames}
      onClick={handleClick}
      type={type}
    >{children}
    </button>
  );

}

function Example() {

  function handleClick(e) {
    console.log(e.target.textContent);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Button
        classname="ticket"
        type="button"
        handleClick={handleClick}
      >Click me</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```css
.btn { border: 2px solid red; }
.ticket { background-color: #55dd44;  }
.ticket:hover { background-color: #ff3377; border: 1px solid blue; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Button.js class, you have to assign an external class that you provided from another component as a prop.

In your Button.js class, you have to update your code just like below

***if functional component***

```
<button className= {`btn ${props.className}`} onClick = {onclick} type = {type}> {children}/button>
```

Note:- make sure to use props as a parameter on functional component

***if class-based component***

```
<button className= {`btn ${this.props.className}`} onClick = {onclick} type = {type}> {children}/button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I was watching a tutorial online but the guy didn't explain why he did that but I understood now.

Comment: you can also add multiple class name in any component just like 
className={['class1', 'class2', 'class3'].join(' ')}

Answer (score 0):

What you can do it, you can pass the `className` as `props` to your `button` component, and use it in there.

Here is the example how you can achieve this:

```js
// button.js
const Button = ({ onClick, type, children, className }) => {
  return (
    <button className={`btn ${className}`} onClick={onclick} type={type}>
      {children}
    </button>
  );
};

export default Button;
```

And in your `app.js` file you can pass `className` as a props, like this:

```js
// app.js
import Button from "./button";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Button onClick={() => {}} type="text" className="abc def">
      Click Me
    </Button>
  );
};

export default App;
```